# Disabled Add Reference in Solution Explorer on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and I want to add reference to make a project as said in this [guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRNro.png), but for some reason it is disabled.

Here is my printscreen picture, it explains it all.

[image]

Comment: Any chance you are currently running the project in debug mode?

Comment: did you try to stop the debugging?

Comment: yes, it was in debugging mode, i stoped it, and now i can add references, thanks you all for the help.

Answer (score 6):

You probably try to *add reference* when you debugging your code. Stop the debugging and you are free to add reference.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not in **Debugging Mode**. Add Reference option usually got disabled in debugging mode.